# DynamoDB : UUID vs combination Natural ID + timestamp

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Assume a model dealing with users. Users are stored in a table called `Users`. Every user is uniquely identified by some natural identifier (partition key). Every user may have zero or more reports stored in the `Reports` table.

I can think of two ways to design the `Reports` table:

1. A partition key consisting of a UUID
2. A partition key consisting of the user natural identifier and, a sort key consisting of a timestamp when the report was created

With a timestamp precision at milliseconds level, it is safe to assume that no more than one report can be generated for a given user during the same millisecond (second precision should also be safe).

What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the distribution of reports per user. If it is typical for users to have very few reports each (say < 100 each) or if all users will have almost the same number of reports then you can go with user ID and time stamp.

But if you expect that some users will have a lot more reports that the majority then you should opt for UUID with a GSI for looking up records by user id.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate how the distribution of reports per user should impact the decision? Why using natural ID + timestamp a "bad" solution if the number of reports per user is big?

Comment: DynamoDB scales very well under a uniform distribution. That is to say the more random the keys for your items the better you are off. When you have a composite key (partition+sort) then you should aim to have approximately the same number of items for each partition key.

Comment: My partition key will be a personal identifier which should be random enough. The number of reports per user will be varying among users but will be relatively low. I understand then that the reports will be well distributed among the different partitions. Thanks!

Comment: As long as you put some defences in place to prevent hotspots (ie users with disproportionately many reports compared to the average) then you will be fine

Comment: What are the cons of using UUID instead (excluding the necessity to generate them)? What are the cons of using a global secondary index?

Comment: GSIs have to be provisioned similar to tables, so it will cost more. And you are limited in how many GSIs you can have for each table